# Не работает бот, vkbottle

Tags: python, бот

Написал код для бота в беседу класса, но по итогу, ровно по такой же структуре, как и другой рабочий бот - он не работает. В чем проблема, я не знаю.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import vkbottle
from vkbottle.bot import Bot, Message
from vkbottle import keyboard, KeyboardButtonColor, Text, OpenLink, Location, EMPTY_KEYBOARD
from vkbottle.tools.dev_tools.keyboard.button import KeyboardButton
from vkbottle.tools.dev_tools.keyboard.keyboard import Keyboard
from settiings import settings, tokens

bot = Bot(token=tokens)

@bot.on.message(text="/расписание")
async def handler(message: Message):
    keyboard = Keyboard()

    Keyboard(inline=True)

    keyboard.add(Text("Расписание"), color=KeyboardButtonColor.SECONDARY)
    await message.answer(f'Сейчас расписания нету.', keyboard=keyboard)


bot.run_forever()
```

Все галочки у меня стоят, longpoll включен, токен вписал нужный. Не отвечает именно в беседе, при этом я и задавал @bot.on.chat_message, и обычный мессадж, не работает.

Comment: Может быть, для полноты картины Вы добавите код того бота, который работает?

Comment: Привет, ошибку исправил, но появилась другая проблема.

Comment: Я добавил его в беседу, но теперь когда я отправляю команду "Расписание", он на нее отвечает, но когда нажимаю на кнопку, то отправляется "Расписание" с упоминанием паблика до команды, на это он не отвечает.

Comment: @bot.on.chat_message(text=["Расписание", "@for10arsp Расписание"])